# Mongoose Schema with different objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a base schema that looks like that:

```
let Entry = new Schema({
key: String,
items: [
    {
        id: Number,
        text: String
    }
]});
```

But the item schema can vary, I want that I can append new object that have the same schema like the the base schema. So that an object in items can also have own items. Example:

```
let Entry = new Schema({
key: String,
items: [
    {
        id: Number,
        text: String
    },
    {
        key: String,
        items: [
            ...
        ]
    }
]
});
```

And so on... so that I can have maybe 4 normal item objects with `id` and `text`, or maybe also nested objects in `items`, which again have `key` and `items[...]` properties, with the possibility to repeat the process even further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be to utilise the Mixed type from Mongoose.

Say something like this:

```
let Entry = new Schema({
key: String,
items: [
    {
        id: Number,
        text: String,
        data: {
            type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
            default: {}
        }
    }
]});
```

Now this example places any 'custom' fields inside a data property, unsure if that would suffice for your needs.

Usage

```
const newEntry = new Entry({
    id: 1,
    text: "foobar",
    data: {
        hello: "world",
        isCorrect: true
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you could just set strict to false on the schema.

```
let Entry = new Schema({
key: String,
items: [
    {
        id: Number,
        text: String
    }
]}, { strict: false});
```

Usage

```
const newEntry = new Entry({
    id: 1,
    text: "foobar",
    hello: "world",
    isCorrect: true
});
```

My personal preference would be the first option, at least this way, looking at the schema, I know that there is a mixed 'bag' of data in each record, contained within the 'data' field. Both are documented methods defined within the mongoose documentation, and hence perfectly valid. Pick your poison :)

Refs:

Mixed Schema Type documentation:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed

strict Schema option documentation:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict